# How can I show a trip on a map, color-coded by how long the trip actually took?

Tags: qgis, google-maps, cartography, excel, route

I have a series of origin and destination addresses in a spreadsheet, with start times and arrival times for each. I'd like to plot them on a map, with a line between each origin and destination, color-coded by how long the trip took.

For example, if the trip from point A to point B took 1 hours and 45 minutes, display a red line between the points, and if the trip from point C to point D took 37 minutes, display the line between them in green.

My preference would be to use a free tool, but if the only way to do this is with a commercial offering, I'd like to know that as well.

Comment: welcome o GIS SE. this can be done with QGIS but it might be long to explain if you've never used it. For the symbology, you could start with this tutorial (you are looking for "graduated colors". http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-styling-vector-data-in-qgis.html Please edit your question if you have a more specific issue.

Comment: Do you have the address geocoding figured out or is that part of the question?

Comment: @underdark, the addresses are geocoded.

Comment: take a look at this if this works http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/plugins/leaflet/v1.0/routing

Comment: That looks promising, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to support multiple routes on a map: http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/471578